# Decreasing Policy Rates but Increasing Banking Rates on Loans

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation, interest-rate

In Turkey, we have been experiencing a chronic problem: Inflation. Since first quarter of 2021 central bank has been decreasing the policy rate, which is related to a political situation. However, this lower policy rates doesn't seem to work because banking rates have been increasing on a huge scale. Can we say that high levels of inflation plays a big role in the observation that high rates that private banks provide? I thought because banks are unable to receive enough deposits from savers due to lower rates compared to inflation, which fluctuates between 50 and 70 percent. And also the profitability of making loans at low rates is lower in the high inflation era, banks' are willing to make loans at higher rates. Would it be a logical interpretation of the current situation? I would like to know more detailed interpretation by economists on especially the idea of real interest rates. Thanks for your support.

[image]

[image]